# first menu item looking differently, with :first-child element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I´m working on web-page menu, and I want to *.current-menu-item* - current item, to look differently. But first item of this menu should have rounded corners (top left, bottom left). How can I do that, with :first-child element? Thanks.

Ok this is a code snippet
HTML:

```
<ul id="navHead">
<li><a href="#">First</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#navHead{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #454545 url('images/gradient.png') top left repeat-x;
}

#navHead li{
    float: left;
}

#navHead li a{
    display: block;
}
```

Finally, wordpress creates after clicking on an item a new class - `current-menu-item`. It is added to the class specification of current list item. And because navHead is rounded, after clicking on the first item, the left side of navHead becomes non rounded, so I wanted to solve this by this code:

```
#navHead li:first-child .current-menu-item a{      
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;      
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;  
}
```

but nothing happens. I have to use `.current-menu-item` and `li:first-child` in one style. HTML code is adjusted by wordpress, so I have to solve this only in CSS.

Comment: Might help if you setup an example on jsfiddle.com

Comment: share your HTML structure as well

Comment: At a minimum we need to see the HTML.

Comment: Please post the markup and some more CSS to give an idea of how you're styling. I'd want to see the `#navHead li .current-menu-item a` and the `#navHead li .current-menu-item` and the `#navHead li a` and the `#navHead li` styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED ANSWER:

```
#navHead li.current-menu-item:first-child{
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;      
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

This would cause the first li element of #navHead to have rounded corners IF it has the class 'current-menu-item'. I would add as a note though, that the the original border radius is set on '#navHead' not any subsequent elements.

some reference reading for selector syntax and construction: [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: Just a side note, I'm assuming a certain structure to your HTML. Please post HTML for a better answer.

Comment: Yes, that´s right, but I need this border-radius to be only in current menu item (class created by Wordpress), not also in first list item (in time when this class is not created on that list item )

Comment: Post the HTML, and people will be able to give you an accurate response.

Comment: this method hasn´t worked, but I tried `#navHead li{   overflow: hidden;  }`, which worked in my case. But it would be a bad solution, if I created some podmenu in the first child of navHead.

Comment: That would suggest that the .current-menu-item class was asigned to th anchor tag not the li element..